# ASP.NET and SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have to integrate my C# asp.net project with a SQL Server database. I have been reading a lot but can't find the 'best solution'

The way I imagine is to have a class that connects to the database and has all SQL queries inside instead of writing each query in the .cs file of every page.

Is there a complete tutorial on how to do that or am I totally wrong?

Please give me an advice.

I would like to pass objects around instead of constantly querying the database.

Thank you!

Comment: Consider using an **ORM** - an object-relational mapper - like Entity Framework, Dapper.NET or NHibernate - to spare yourself having to fiddle around with untyped columns and rows; an ORM instead provides nice, clean, strongly-typed .NET objects to work with!

Comment: See more on [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) and [Dapper.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212274/A-Look-at-Dapper-NET) - there are tons of ORM's for .NET, but these two are my favorites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start learning the basics of ADO.NET first. The topic of using a database is vast. There are many different options you could select from such as:

- Plain ADO.NET
- ORM
- Entity Framework
- Web Services

and many more...

For starters I recommend you get a book on ADO.NET to get the basics and them move into using a simple ORM or EF and Linq. There are many books and learning materials you can use, here is a taste of some:

[ASP.NET & ADO.NET](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_ado_net.htm)

[SQL Server and ASP.NET](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/934.how-to-use-asp-net-with-sql-server.aspx).